# Evaluating $\int_{2}^{5}\sqrt{\tan{\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)}}\,dx$ using a new (?) trick

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The following identities have been suggested based on formulas in a [previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844145/trigonometric-formula-for-solving-quadratic-equations).

If complex $\theta_1=\cos^{-1}(p)$ and $\theta_2=\sec^{-1}(p)$, where $p\in(-1, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$, then the following relation holds:

> $$e^{i\theta_1}=\frac{1-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2} }{1+\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}}. 
>  \tag{1}\label{463459_1}$$

And for $p\in(-\infty, -1)\cup (0, 1)$, we have

> $$e^{-i\theta_1}=\frac{1-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2} }{1+\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}}. \tag{2}\label{463459_2}$$

If complex $\theta_1=\sin^{-1}(p)$ and $\theta_2=\csc^{-1}(p)$, where $p\in(-\infty, -1)\cup (0, 1)$, then the following relation holds:

> $$ie^{i\theta_1}=-\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}.\tag{3}\label{463459_3}$$

And for $p\in(-1, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$ we have

> $$ie^{-i\theta_1}=\tan\frac{\theta_2}{2}.\tag{4}\label{463459_4}$$

There are several variants that we can obtain by equating (and simplifying) the trigonometric formulas for quadratic equations from [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4844145/trigonometric-formula-for-solving-quadratic-equations).

I have noticed that for certain trigonometric integrals defined over permissible intervals of $p$, the evaluation simplifies considerably. For instance, consider the following definite integral:

> $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)} \,dx.\tag{5}\label{463459_5}$$

[This integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sqrttan%28arccscx%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=5) returns the following:

> No antiderivative could be found within the given time limit, or all
> supported integration methods were tried unsuccessfully. Note that
> many functions don't have an elementary antiderivative.

But it gives an approximation of $1.178881841955109.$

Given that the interval $[2, 5]$ is within the permissible values of $p$, I can use $e^{i\cos^{-1}(p)}=\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}(p)}{2}$ (derived from identities \eqref{463459_1} and \eqref{463459_4}), valid for $p\in[-1, 0) \cup [1, \infty)$, to convert \eqref{463459_5} into

> $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}}\,dx.\tag{6}\label{463459_6}$$

[The same calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28e%5E%28iarccosx%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=5) provides the same answer but now displaying the steps as well. As a second example, compare the solutions of the following definite integrals, coming from identity \eqref{463459_1}:

[$$\int_2^3 \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\tan\left(\frac{\operatorname{arcsec}(x)}{2}\right)+1}-1} \, dx\tag{7}\label{463459_7}$$](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28%282%2F%28tan%28%28arcsecx%29%2F2%29%2B1%29-1%29%5E%281%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=3)

[$$\int_2^3 e^{\frac{i\arccos(x)}{2}} \,dx\tag{8}\label{463459_8}$$](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28e%5E%28iarccosx%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29&lbound=2&ubound=3)

Judge for yourself which one is simpler to solve between \eqref{463459_7} and \eqref{463459_8}.

I have spent quite some time applying these substitutions and have come to the conclusion that these identities make certain trigonometric integrals less tedious. This leads me to the question: **Was this trick known in the world of integrals?**

**EDITED**. Not exactly the same technique , but I think this is somehow related to my question.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_using_Euler%27s_formula), using Euler's formula, any trigonometric function may be written in terms of complex exponential functions, namely  $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ and then integrated. This technique is often simpler and faster than using trigonometric identities or integration by parts, and is sufficiently powerful to integrate any rational expression involving trigonometric functions.

Crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463459/identities-that-simplify-tedious-integrals).

This story will continue on my [blog](https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2024/03/integration-using-some-euler-like.html).

Comment: Complexification formulas are great and it seems like this simplifies the right away. You just have to be careful that when you draw triangles and take square roots the signs make sense at every step, especially the end, to line up with your original integrand.

Comment: The simplication in real space is convenient as well $$\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}2=x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

Comment: @Quanto: Yes, although I must say that the substitution I have used is not the best. The substitution $$e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}=\tan{\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}},$$ valid for $x\in[-1, 0) \cup [1, \infty)$ is simpler.

Comment: Rewriting in terms of radicals becomes tedious in other, more complicated cases. I prefer to stick with the *complexification formulas*, as Ninad has called them.

Comment: Another example of a complexification formula is treating $$\int\cos(\log x)dx = \operatorname{Re}\left\{\int x^i dx\right\}$$ in case you haven't come across the term before. It comes from a variety of places, one such prominent elementary example being complexifying vector spaces to add pairwise dimensional structure to go from a $2n$ to $n$ dimensional space.

Comment: Why do we have to integrate $\sqrt{e^{i\arccos(x)}}$ in order to evaluate $\int_2^5 \sqrt{\tan\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)} \,dx$? Why can't we just use (4) to write $i e^{-i\arcsin(x)}=\tan\left(\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}\right)$ and then integrate $\sqrt{i e^{-i\arcsin(x)}}$?

Comment: @DavidK: Because I realized that this transformation is simpler. The closed form is also simpler than using $(4)$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says equation $(1)$ [is not true for $0 < p < 1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5Be%2Ci*arccos%5C%2840%29.5%5C%2841%29%5D+-+Divide%5B1-tan%5C%2840%290.5arcsec%5C%2840%29.5%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C1%2Btan%5C%2840%290.5arcsec%5C%2840%29.5%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5D&lang=es), but instead equation $(2)$ is true. It says neither is true at $p=-1$ (the value on the right-hand side is undefined). Remind me how you decided that equation $(1)$ is true for all $p \geq -1$?

Comment: @DavidK: I decided empirically. I'm writing a note and still pondering some details. Tomorrow I'll review the constraints of $p$ and edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: With Mathematica: $$\int_2^5 \sqrt{\tan \left(\frac{1}{2} \csc ^{-1}(x)\right)} \, dx=\int_2^5 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{-1+x^2}}} \, dx=-\frac{1}{3} \left(7 \sqrt{2}\right)+4
   \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{6}$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Yes, but check the comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463459/solving-impossible-integrals-with-a-new-trick?_gl=1*1cuyx4z*_ga*MTQyNzE4MzIyOC4xNjM4MTQ5Njk3*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTcwODcwNDM1My4xMjg3LjEuMTcwODcwNjYyOC4wLjAuMA..). Although I still need to correct the restrictions on $p$ in MO.

Comment: @DavidK: Consider the identity $e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}=\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}$. The exponential $e^{i\cos^{-1}(x)}$ can be rewritten as $x+i\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}(x)}{2}$ as $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ (as Quanto mentioned above). Assume $x$ is real. Then the equation $i\sqrt{1-x^2}=-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ will only be true if $x\geq1$. In fact, if $x=1$, the equation is clearly true. If $0<x<1$, then $w=1-x^2>0$, so $i\sqrt{w}=-\sqrt{-w}=-i\sqrt{w}$, which is not true. Therefore, this identity holds for the interval $[1, \infty)$. Similar arguments can be constructed for other cases.

Comment: @DavidK: We also have that $\tan{\frac12\sec^{-1}(x)}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$. Rewriting the right side of identity $(1)$ in terms of these radicals also simplifies to $x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$. Therefore, this identity is also valid for the interval $[1, \infty)$ and **not** for $[0, 1)$, since for $x=0$ we get something like $i=-i$, which is not true.

Comment: @DavidK: Consider again the equation $i\sqrt{1-x^2}=-\sqrt{x^2-1}$. For $x>1$, we have $w=1-x^2<0$, and therefore we have $i\sqrt{-w}=-\sqrt{w}$, which is true.

Comment: I see you changed the conditions under which you use $(1)$ versus $(2)$, so now they agree with Wolfram Alpha. That resolves my previous comment, thank you.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $-\frac{7 \sqrt{2}}{3}+4 \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{6}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Yes, but can *Mathematica* solves this one? $$\int_{2}^{3}  \frac{{1 - \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}{{1 + \tan\frac{{\sec^{-1}x}}{2}}}\sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}}\,dx$$  I also posted my question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463459/solving-impossible-integrals-with-a-new-trick) with some variations. The identities I have presented here definitely simplify some nearly impossible integrals.

Comment: @EmmanuelJoséGarcía Let $x=\sec(2t)$ then yes it can. In particular, $$\int_{2}^{3}\frac{1-\tan\frac{\sec^{-1}x}{2}}{1+\tan\frac{\sec^{-1}x}{2}}\sqrt{\tan\frac{\csc^{-1}x}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{5}\left(31\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{6}-36\right).$$

Comment: After applying the substitution $x=\sec(2t)$, one arrives at $$I=2\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}3}\sec(2t)\tan(2t)\cdot\frac{1-\tan(t)}{1+\tan(t)}\sqrt{\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+t\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{2+3\sin(2t)}{1+\sin(2t)}\sqrt{\frac{\cos t-\sin t}{\cos t+\sin t}}\Bigg]_{\pi/6}^{\sec^{-1}(3)/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

@EmmanuelJoséGarcía.  Yes *Mathematica* can solve your harder equation:  $\left(\frac{1}{192}+\frac{i}{192}\right) \left(72 i \log
   \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{16}+8 \text{$\#$1}^{14}+44 \text{$\#$1}^{12}-136
   \text{$\#$1}^{10}+230 \text{$\#$1}^8-136 \text{$\#$1}^6+44 \text{$\#$1}^4+8
   \text{$\#$1}^2+1\&,7\right]\right)-(6-6 i) \sqrt[4]{3}
   \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^4+108\&,2\right] \log
   \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{16}+4 \text{$\#$1}^{14}+16 \text{$\#$1}^{12}-44
   \text{$\#$1}^{10}+82 \text{$\#$1}^8-44 \text{$\#$1}^6+16 \text{$\#$1}^4+4
   \text{$\#$1}^2+1\&,7\right]\right)-36 i \log
   \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{16}+4 \text{$\#$1}^{14}+16 \text{$\#$1}^{12}-44
   \text{$\#$1}^{10}+82 \text{$\#$1}^8-44 \text{$\#$1}^6+16 \text{$\#$1}^4+4
   \text{$\#$1}^2+1\&,7\right]\right)+36 i \log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^8+8
   \text{$\#$1}^7+44 \text{$\#$1}^6-136 \text{$\#$1}^5+230 \text{$\#$1}^4-136
   \text{$\#$1}^3+44 \text{$\#$1}^2+8 \text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]\right)-\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt[4]{3} \log \left(1+(1-i) \sqrt[4]{3}-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^4-8748\&,3\right]-372 i 6^{3/4} \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2}\right)+942 i \sqrt[4]{2}
   \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4};\frac{3}{4};2\right)+744 i 6^{3/4} \,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2}\right)-2640 i \sqrt[4]{2}
   \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};2\right)-8 i 6^{3/4} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2}\right)+64 i \sqrt[4]{2} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};2\right)+(-240+120 i) \sqrt[4]{2}-375\
   2^{3/4}+(72-72 i) \sqrt[4]{3}+(162-162 i) 3^{3/4}+15 i 2^{3/4} \sqrt{657+200
   \sqrt{2}}-36 \log \left(1-(1-i) \sqrt[4]{2}-i \sqrt{2}\right)+36 \log \left(1+(1-i)
   \sqrt[4]{2}-i \sqrt{2}\right)-72 i \log \left(1-i \sqrt[4]{3}\right)+36 \log
   \left(1-(1-i) \sqrt[4]{3}-i \sqrt{3}\right)-(36-18 i) \log \left(1+(1-i) \sqrt[4]{3}-i
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$